# SPMetal.exe : could not create entity file

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, spmetal

I use this command:

```
SPMetal /web:http://intranet.contoso.com/sites/Lab05 /code:Entities.cs /language:csharp
```

for creating the entity file Entities.cs, but I get the error:

> Must specify source code language..

But I have specified the source code language, so what's wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to leave out the /language parameter? It isn't required when you /code ends with .cs. Have you tried to use `-` instead of `/` in front of parameters?

Answer (score 1):

The error is not because of /language or - parameter. I need to put one space at the end of every parameter and it solves the problem after getting one warning message.